# Rails jquery datepicker can't find html

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the jquery-ui datepicker in a Rails app.  I have 2 forms for entering data.  One is a regular Rails view page and the other is a Bootstrap modal. The modal one isn't working.

This is the coffeescript (I'm assuming this will work for both):

```
  $("#expense_exp_date").datepicker dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
```

This is the Rails view code and corresponding html:

```
<%= f.input :exp_date, :as => :string, :label => 'Date', :class => 'calendar hasDatepicker', :input_html => {:value => Date.today.to_s} %>
<input class="string required hasDatepicker" id="expense_exp_date" name="expense[exp_date]" size="50" type="text" value="2013-01-21">
```

This is the Bootstrap modal code and corresponding html:

```
  <%= f.input :exp_date, :as => :string, :label => 'Date', :class => 'calendar hasDatepicker', :input_html => {:value => Date.today.to_s}, :input_html => {:style => 'width: 180px'} %>
<input class="string required" id="expense_exp_date" name="expense[exp_date]" size="50" style="width: 180px" type="text">
```

Why is "hasDatepicker" missing from the modal html?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass the `class` option inside the `input_html` Option hash:

```
<%= f.input :exp_date, :as => :string, :label => 'Date', 
            :input_html => {
                             :value => Date.today.to_s, 
                             :class => 'calendar hasDatepicker'} %>
```

Comment: Mr Yoshiji , happy 3k ! Glad to see it .